# how to join all the tables without using any condition

Tags: oracle11g

all the below results are not related to each other wheras we cannot use any condition.

```
    ID
----------
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
```

7 rows selected.

```
NAME
-----------------
SRUJAN
DEERAJ
VINEETH
CHANIKYA
LAVANYA
KAVITHA
BUNNY
```

7 rows selected.

```
   AGE
----------
    23
    24
    26
    25
    29
    28
    24
```

7 rows selected.

```
 ADDRESS
 -------------
 NAGARAM
 BANDLAGUDA
 UPPAL
 KUKATPALLY
 HB COLONY
 MOULALI
 BOUDHA NAGAR
```

7 rows selected.

```
SALARY
----------
 12000
 13000
 14000
 15000
 16000
 17000
 18000
```

7 rows selected.

I USED

```
SQL>select id,name,age,address,salary from table1,table2,table3,table4,table5;
```

but it showing 16807 rows selected

i want to get only one table.
please suggest a query.

Comment: You cannot join the way you want without a condition

Comment: Which id should go with which name, which age, etc.? If you are using this to generate sample data (for example, so that you can test your code), then a random matching may be OK. This can be done in two ways - either a purely random match or by using sorting: id = 1 will get the first name (alphabetically), the lowest age, lowest salary etc. Will either of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible join between 2 tables having only 1 columns and both having no relation is cross join. You cannot avoid it. And the same you are getting when you tried to join. The best way for you is to create a sequence as ID and then call it in your select statement of table2.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ 
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE;

select TEST_SEQ.nextval ID,col1 NAME
 from table2;
```

Comment: one more suggestion please: i need a query that joins 5 tables table1,table2,table3,table4,table5  having only single columns id,name,age,address,salary.

Comment: Please post it as a query with proper table description and sample data.

Comment: It would be easier if you make a table and make each as one of the columns and store it. its not possible to join such tables with single columns without any relation . It will give Cartesian result. That means each table row is joined with each other 7 table's each row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using inner joins. This solution matches the lowest id with the first name in alphabetical order, the lowest age, etc.

If instead of this ordered matching you need random matching, that is easy to do as well: in the `over...` clause of the `prep` tables, change the `order by` clause to `order by dbms_random.value()` (in all places).

In the solution below I use only the first three tables, but the same works for any number of input tables.

```
with
     tbl_id ( id ) as (
       select 1 from dual union all
       select 2 from dual union all
       select 3 from dual union all
       select 4 from dual union all
       select 5 from dual union all
       select 6 from dual union all
       select 7 from dual
     ),
     tbl_name ( name ) as (
       select 'SRUJAN'   from dual union all
       select 'DEERAJ'   from dual union all
       select 'VINEETH'  from dual union all
       select 'CHANIKYA' from dual union all
       select 'LAVANYA'  from dual union all
       select 'KAVITHA'  from dual union all
       select 'BUNNY'    from dual
     ),
     tbl_age ( age ) as (
       select 23 from dual union all
       select 24 from dual union all
       select 26 from dual union all
       select 25 from dual union all
       select 29 from dual union all
       select 28 from dual union all
       select 24 from dual
     ),
     prep_id ( id, rn ) as (
       select id, row_number() over (order by id) from tbl_id
     ),
     prep_name ( name, rn ) as (
       select name, row_number() over (order by name) from tbl_name
     ),
     prep_age ( age , rn ) as (
       select age, row_number() over (order by age) from tbl_age
     )
select i.id, n.name, a.age
from   prep_id i inner join prep_name n on i.rn = n.rn
                 inner join prep_age  a on i.rn = a.rn
;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID NAME            AGE
---------- -------- ----------
         1 BUNNY            23
         2 CHANIKYA         24
         3 DEERAJ           24
         4 KAVITHA          25
         5 LAVANYA          26
         6 SRUJAN           28
         7 VINEETH          29

 7 rows selected
```